# Displaying elements in Yii2 Gridview

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Am trying to display a grid view in the yii2 view action of a controller but I get an error of Call to a member function getTotalCount() on a non-object

I have two related tables that is table Cases which is related to table Accusers as below

Case Model coe:

```
    public function getAccusers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Accuser::className(), ['case_ref_no' => 'ref_no']);
}
```

Accusers model relation

```
 public function getCaseRefNo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cases::className(), ['ref_no' => 'case_ref_no']);
}
```

In the case controller the action index has a grid view  in which I select the view action

In the view action I have passed grid view which basically I would wish that it displays the records of Accusers related to a certain case (That is the case ref no just as in the relationship above)

The case controller code: Action view

```
public function actionView($id)
{          
     $dataProvider = Accuser::find()
     ->where(['case_ref_no'=>$id])
    ->all();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

The view page (code)

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
```

...........

```
                 <?= GridView::widget([
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            'showPageSummary' =>false,
                            //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                            'columns' => [
                                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


                                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
                            ],
                        ]); ?>
```

I used 'showPageSummary' =>false, but I still get that error of Call to a member function getTotalCount() on a non-object

Full accuser model

```
class Accuser extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'accuser';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['fname', 'secname', 'date_of_birth', 'case_ref_no', 'idno'], 'required'],
        [['date_of_birth'], 'safe'],
        [['fname', 'secname', 'case_ref_no', 'idno'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'fname' => 'Fname',
        'secname' => 'Secname',
        'date_of_birth' => 'Date Of Birth',
        'case_ref_no' => 'Case Ref No',
        'idno' => 'Idno',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCaseRefNo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cases::className(), ['ref_no' => 'case_ref_no']);
}
```

}

The var_dump($dataProvider); in the view I got(after changing the find()->all() to find() only

```
  object(yii\db\ActiveQuery)[60]
   public 'sql' => null
   public 'on' => null
   public 'joinWith' => null
   public 'select' => null
   public 'selectOption' => null
   public 'distinct' => null
   public 'from' => null
   public 'groupBy' => null
   public 'join' => null
   public 'having' => null
   public 'union' => null
   public 'params' => 
   array (size=0)
    empty
   private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
     array (size=0)
     empty
   private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
   array (size=0)
    empty
     public 'where' => 
       array (size=1)
     'case_ref_no' => string '#RERADRADAR' (length=11)
   public 'limit' => null
   public 'offset' => null
   public 'orderBy' => null
    public 'indexBy' => null
      public 'modelClass' => string 'frontend\models\Accuser' (length=23)
       public 'with' => null
        public 'asArray' => null
      public 'multiple' => null
     public 'primaryModel' => null
     public 'link' => null
     public 'via' => null
      public 'inverseOf' => null
```

Comment: show the accuser model please

Comment: I have added the accuser model #scaisEdge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dataProvider you should create with the proper class (ActiveDataprovider, ArrayDataProvider or SqlDataProvider ) 
this way and not directly form the query like you have done

```
    $query = Accuser::find()
         ->where(['case_ref_no'=>$id]);

   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

If you think the problem is related to the summary too you should  avoid this using

```
 'summary'=>"",
```

this way

```
<?= GridView::widget([

     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'summary'=>"",
```

Comment: Even after doing it I get the same error of Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::getTotalCount()

Comment: I have update the answer. I think you don't have create teh data provider properly.

Answer (score 0):

change your action to this

```
public function actionView($id)
{          
    $dataProvider = Accuser::find()
    ->where(['case_ref_no'=>$id]);


   return $this->render('view', [
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'model' => $this->findModel($id),
   ]);
}
```

gridview work with dataprovider and find result is your data provider . if you use all() after find your $dataprovider variable is an array of your Accuser object!

Comment: what is the var_dump($dataProvider) result ?

Comment: var dump($ataProvider) result      array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(frontend\models\Accuser)[65]
      private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 1
          'fname' => string 'aa' (length=2)
          'secname' => string 'mwangi' (length=6)
          'date_of_birth' => string '2015-11-11' (length=10)
          'case_ref_no' => string '#RERADRADAR' (length=11)
          'idno' => string '' (length=0)
      private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 1

Comment: 'fname' => string 'aa' (length=2)
          'secname' => string 'mwangi' (length=6)
          'date_of_birth' => string '2015-11-11' (length=10)
          'case_ref_no' => string '#RERADRADAR' (length=11)
          'idno' => string '' (length=0)
      private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_errors' (yii\base\Model) => null
      private '_validators' (yii\base\Model) => null

Comment: private '_scenario' (yii\base\Model) => string 'default' (length=7)
      private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty

Comment: I have updated the question with the var_dump value of the dataProvider for more visibility